# Fortran dll in C# gives Unable to find an entry point error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, fortran, dllimport

requesting some help here. I am trying to consume a fortran dll in my C# app through Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. I have never seen fortran code in my life. So I created a sample dll with a simple program like this in notepad++.

```
subroutine Add(x, y, total)BIND(C,NAME="Add")

!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, ALIAS: 'Add'::Add

integer, intent (in) :: x
integer, intent (in) :: y
integer, intent (inout) :: total   

total = x + y
end subroutine
```

I compiled this code (1 file called console.f90) in Windows 10 using MingW fortran compiler with the following command:

```
gfortran -c -o C:\Users\Desktop\Temp\console.o C:\Users\Desktop\Temp\console.f90
gfortran -shared -mrtd -o C:\Users\Desktop\Temp\console.dll C:\Users\Desktop\Temp\console.o
```

This gave me console.dll.

Now I opened a new C# console project in VS 2017. Changed the architecture to x86(x64 giving me bad format error). Placed the fortran dll (console.dll) in the same folder as my project and included in project and set the property to 'Copy if newer' so it is copied to bin\debug.

Wrote this line for P/Invoke

```
[DllImport("console.dll", EntryPoint = "Add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void Add([In] int x, [In] int y, [In, Out] int t);
```

Then in my Main function used this

```
int a = 12;
int b = 30;
int t = 0;
Add(a, b, t);
```

Though when I run the application, the moment the Add(a,b,t) is executed I get a 'EntryPointNotFound' exception. So I used DependencyWalker and Dumpbin to see if the function is exported and the name is correct. The results below:

[Dumpbin screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp0BV.png)

[Dependency Walker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByOu9.png)

I see my dlls are x86 and other ones are x64 is it the problem? Also the dependency walker showed 3 dll dependency 'lib...'. I placed them also in the project folder and applied the same property. Still no luck. Any help is appreciated here. Thank you

Comment: Dependency Walker output is misleading. Use dumpbin to find out the name of the export. Which you did. And then name is fine. So the C# program is clearly loading a different DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I had set Platform selection to Debug which was causing the problem. Adding x86 option through Configuration manager and selecting the same fixed my problem.